# How to move elements on scroll in React.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, scroll

I am trying to create an E-commerce Store and **I'm a beginner in React.JS**. What I want is for **5 images to come together on top of eachother when the user scrolls**. (so they should move TranslateX on scroll). Previously, on Vanilla Javascript I would have added a window.addEventListener('scroll') and then set a value like value = window.scrollY and then I would have selected the image I wanted to move and simply translateX or Y based on that value.

However, I'm not sure how to do this in React. Where can I set the window event listener? Is there a state needed, or useEffect?

**I'm attaching an image** so you can clearly see what I am trying to do:

[image]

What I have in react is the **"Scroll" component** which contains **2 divs**

**-1 div on the left 2/3 flex size containing all the images that should come together**
-1 div on the right 1/3 flex size containing the text and the button

**inside the left div I have 5 images**, and in CSS i've used position absolute to position them on top of eachother (they are all PNGs so they have transparent background).

How would I go about implementing this on my website?

**HUGE thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

You can save the scrollY in a useState, which you then use to transofrm your images. The window listeners can be loaded inside a useEffect.
It (could) look like this:

```
const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrollY(window.scrollY);
    };
    handleScroll();

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

(You may have to add some ESLint rules if you use it)

Comment: You're a hero! Thank you so much!

Comment: halo, i try to implement this code, but the state is still 0, whats wrong with that? @Ironessence

Comment: @FarhatDje Its because of closure, empty dependency array means useEffect will only be called on the first render and window.scrollY inside handleScroll will always be 0.